# How to create an Azure alert to notify about any resource deletion

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

Looking for some help around Azure alerts.

I need to get notified whenever any Azure resource is deleted. From what I have read so far I know an alert can be created at a resource level. But it will be too cumbersome to setup alert for each resource individually.

Ideally I would like to have a rule set up at Subscription level or Resource Group level which notify when **any** resource in Sub/ Resource group is deleted.

Will highly appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could, actually just [stream activity logs to azure log analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-collect) and then you could use a simple query like so:

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue endswith "DELETE"
```

and then just click that `+ New alert rule` button and your are all set.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Alert level at the Subscription level is [`NOT supported`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/231545-diagnostics-and-monitoring/suggestions/12444534-monitor-resource-creation-in-an-azure-subscription). However, you can upvote the request here.

The only way to do is to create the rule for each resource as you mentioned in the question.